# How to disable reordering of a specific (last) column of a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a data grid in my application, Where I need to make last column of the data grid always stays as the last column, It cannot be drag on to another column and other columns cannot be dropped into this last column. But the problem is since this column is a data grid template column, disabling of drag and drop can not be achieved as per the most of the online articles has described.So how can I achieve this. How ever what I want is always last column of the grid should be stays as the last column, It cannot be moved.other columns can be drag and dropped. So how can I achieve this? Any guidance or advice will be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but in case you are trying to disable column reordering set the `DataGrid.CanUserReorderColumns` property to `false`:

```
<DataGrid CanUserReorderColumns="False" />
```

---

The previous solution disables column reordering for *all* columns.
Since you only want the last column to be pinned, you have to extend `DataGrid` to implement this behavior by overriding [`DataGrid.OnColumnReordering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.oncolumnreordering?view=netframework-4.8):

**CustomDataGrid.cs**

```
class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
  private int ReorderingColumnOriginalDispalyIndex { get; set; }

  #region Overrides of DataGrid

  protected override void OnColumnReordering(DataGridColumnReorderingEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnColumnReordering(e);

    // Check if the reordering column is the last column
    if (e.Column.DisplayIndex == this.Columns.Count - 1)
    {
      // This is the last column, therefore abort reordering
      e.Cancel = true;
    }    
  }

  protected override void OnColumnReordered(DataGridColumnEventArgse) 
  {
    base.OnColumnReordered(e);

    // Check if the reordered column is the last column (after the pinned column)
    if (e.Column.DisplayIndex == this.Columns.Count - 1)
    {
      // This is the last column.
      // A movable column was moved to an illegal position.
      // Coerce position by moving it to the position before the pinned column
      e.Column.DisplayIndex = this.Columns.Count - 2;
    }    
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**Usage**

```
<CustomDataGrid x:Name="DataGridWhichHasTheLastColumnPinned" />
```

Comment: I want to disable drag and drop of last column of the grid, other columns can be dragged and dropped but last column should not be dragged and dropped

Comment: I'm implementing my application using MVVM patern, So I have a doubt that will this implementation violates MVVM pattern ?

Comment: _MVVM_ is about separating the view from the business logic. Nothing else. To achieve this the pattern introduces an additional layer (view model) and makes use of the frameworks binding features to decouple the view.

Comment: No, it definitely doesn't violate the _MVVM_  pattern. I can assure you. It's a very clean solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @BionicCode for your kindness. And Thank you so much for your great explanations !! It helped me a lot :)

Comment: So this OnColumnReordering has to be a command according to MVVM pattern. am I right? @BionicCode

Comment: No, it's not a command, it's an override of a virtual `DataGrid` method. It is invoked by the `DataGrid` internals when ever a column is about to be reordered by the user. It's a protected virtual event invokator ([`DataGrid.OnColumnReordering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.oncolumnreordering?view=netframework-4.8)). You derive from `DataGrid` and override those methods e.g. `OnAutoGenerating` is invoked when auto-generate is enabled and executing.

Comment: Alternatively you can subscribe to the `DataGrid.ColumnReordering` event. But this is less convenient and requires to have direct access (reference)  to the `DataGrid` instance.

Comment: So you are telling me, In xaml write the event handler  ColumnReordering="OnColumnReordering" and then put this code  in the codebehind. If I put it in the code behind I can not extend from the DataGrid class since codebehind is already extends from Page class. Correct me if I'm wrong . @BionicCode

Comment: No that's not what I am telling you. I showed you how to extend the `DataGrid`class and implement the required behavior by overriding a virtual method of  the `DataGrid`. You have to create a new class. **1.** Create a new file called _CustomDataGrid.cs_ (make the filename match the class name) and then **2.** paste my code into it. I updated my answer by adding a usage example to show how to use this class. It's like the default `DataGrid` with the additional feature that it has the last column pinned.

Comment: Now That specific column cannot be dragged but other columns can be drag and dropped after that column. So anyway position of the column changes.I want to make that column always as last column. It should not be moved.How Can I achieve this? Any guidance on this @BionicCode

Comment: Right now, the last column can't be reordered ie.e moved. You want to prevent other columns to be moved past the pinned column?

Comment: I updated the code by adding another ovreride: `OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged`. I didn't tested the code. PLease let me know if it is working. Any movable column that was moved past the pinned column will be placed before the pinned column, after the user's drag operation has completed.

Comment: base.OnColumnReordering(e); of OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged, throws an error "cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumnEventArgs' to 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumnReorderingEventArgs' "

Comment: Thank you. There was a copy&paste error inside `OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged`. It must be `base.OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged(e)`. I fixed the code.

Comment: @sm1184 I updated the code and changed the second override from `OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged` to  `OnColumnReordered`. This should work as expected. Sorry that I couldn't return to this question earlier.

Answer (score -1):

> C#

```
this.datagrid.AllowDraggingRows = false;
this.datagrid.AllowDrop = false;
```

> XAML

```
<Syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="datagrid" 
AllowDraggingRows="False"
AllowDrop="False"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"/>
```

Comment: `Syncfusion:SfDataGrid` ? what if OP isn't using this component suite?

Comment: Simply : 
In order to add Syncfusion control manually in XAML, by  doing the below steps,

1- Add the below required assembly references to the project,
`Syncfusion.Data.WPF`
`Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF`
`Syncfusion.Shared.WPF`
Import Syncfusion WPF schema [http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf] or `SfDataGrid` control namespace `Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid` in XAML page.
Declare `SfDataGrid` control in XAML page.

Comment: This is not about Syncfusion. Please remove all Syncfusion references and use simple `Windows.Conytols.DataGrid` I'm your example.

Comment: And forgot to mention I'm using MVVM pattern in this appliction. So will above answer  violates MVVM pattern? @OsamaAbuBaker

Comment: @BionicCode can u please show a exampe using Windows.Conytols.Datagrid

Comment: @sm1184 What exactly do you mean with drag&drop? Like file drag&drop or  column moving?

Comment: @BionicCode Column moving

Comment: @sm1184 Thank you. I think the solution I gave you was solving the problem, wasn't it?

Comment: Actually that CustomDataGrid extends from DataGrid Class , But In my code behind it extends from UserControl class.also since multiple inheritance also not allowed, I was unable to solve the problem. Any guidance or advice on this will be great help! Thanks again @BionicCode

Comment: @sm1184 Sorry, but what the heck are you doing? ;) No problem. I posted how to implement an extended DataGrid: I called it `CustomDataGrid`. As I wrote before in my previous comment, you have to copy the code into a new file -it's a new class,a new control. Now in your existing XAML code just replace the DataGrid with the new CustomDataGrid. Done. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: And don't create a new UserControl. Just a simple class, a naked .cs file where you copy my code to.

Comment: @sm1184 You're welcome. Nice that you got it working ;)